# Optimizing log regex in Powershell

Tags: regex, powershell, logging

We have 2 SMTP gates that spew out text `.log` files (usually around 10-30MB a pop) for about a weeks worth of data. In total, both are usually around ~1.2GB in size.

I have (2) read-only shares setup to the log directories and am trying to parse log entries using `Select-String` (e.g. say I wanted to see if an email by "bdole" came in. If all I wanted was to simply get hits on line numbers, it's not that bad.

However, I want to get the entire "log entry". My initial research says I need to read the entire log's contents at once and then do a regex against that. So, that's what I'm doing, for nearly 200 files.

However, I don't think it's the i/o that is the real issue. I'm spawning ~200 threads (one for each file) and capping out at 20 threads. The initial 20 threads takes some time to run. I put in some debugging code and went back to single-thread; it seems that simply regexing the contents of the one 10-20MB file takes a LONG time.

I suspect that the regex I have written is somehow very inadequate in terms of speed (it works in the sense if I let it run over night, it works fine.) Plus, network I/O is pretty low (peaking at 0.6% of a 2Ggpbs connection) while CPU/RAM are extremely high.

**Ideal log entries look like this:**

```
---- SMTPRS log entry made at mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss
Incoming SMTP call from x.x.x.x at HH:mm:ss.
<<< 220 mail.foo.com
>>> QUIT
<<< 221 mail.foo.com closing
Incoming SMTP call from x.x.x.x completed at HH:mm:ss.
```

The only reliable delimiter is the starting `----` (sometimes it does/doesn't end with a `----`)

The contents of the "log entries" can be extremely variable, including notices of blocked connections, etc.

**the regex I am using**

```
(?sm)----((?!----).*?)(log entry)((?!----).*?)(#USERINPUT#)((?!----).*?)----
```

where `#USERINPUT#` is being replaced by what is passed to the script.

**parsing code**
After getting a list of filepaths using `gci`

```
if ( !(Test-Path $path) ) {
            write-error "issue accessing $path"
        } else {
            try {
                $buffer = [io.file]::ReadAllText($path)
            }
            catch {
                $errArray += $path
                $_
            }
            [string[]]$matchBuffer = @()
            $matchBuffer += $entrySeperator
            $matchBuffer += $_
            $matchBuffer += $entrySeperator
            $matchBuffer += $buffer | Select-String $regex -AllMatches |
            % {$_.Matches} |
            % {$_.Value; $entrySeperator} 

            if ($errArray) {
                write-warning "There were errors, probably in accessing files. "
                $errArray
            }

            $fileName = (gi $path).Name
            sc -path $tmpDir\$fileName -value $matchBuffer
            $matchBuffer | Out-String
```

---

I'm almost wondering if parsing the "hits" (e.g. XXXX.LOG on LINE 21) and working backwards reconstructing the log entry from context would be faster/better.

Comment: Are you locked into parsing the logs as plain, unstructured text with PowerShell? There must be other tools/systems/platforms that are better-suited to digging through log data like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Description

You have a couple problems with your expression:

- by including the `----` at the start and end of your match regex, you might end up missing the next entry in the log, and you'll miss the last entry of the log
- with your construct `((?!----).*?)` it looks like you're trying to limit the amount of matches the `.*?` makes. However the construct only checks once to see that then next 4 characters arn't `----` then it goes on to match the `.*?`. You would be better off replacing this construct with `((?:(?!----).)*)`. Since this construct is self terminating you don't need to worry about the using the `?` to prevent greedyness. The bad news is that the construct is slightly less efficient then simply using `([^\r\n]*?)` to match known entries in the first line and  `(.*?)(?=^----|\Z)` to match the body of the log.
- Assuming that the reliable text `----` will always be at the start of a line, then you can also include the start of line anchor `^`

`(?m)^----\s(.*?)\s(log\sentry)\s(.*?)\s(mm\/dd\/yyyy\sHH:mm:ss)(?sm).*?^(.*?)(?=^----|\Z)`

[image]

## Example

**Powershell Example**

```
$String = '---- 1 SMTPRS log entry made at mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss
Incoming SMTP call from x.x.x.x at HH:mm:ss.
<<< 220 mail.foo.com
>>> QUIT
<<< 221 mail.foo.com closing
Incoming SMTP call from x.x.x.x completed at HH:mm:ss.
---- 2 SMTPRS log entry made at mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss ----
Incoming SMTP call from x.x.x.x at HH:mm:ss.
<<< 220 mail.foo.com
>>> QUIT
<<< 221 mail.foo.com closing
Incoming SMTP call from x.x.x.x completed at HH:mm:ss.
---- 3 SMTPRS log entry made at mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss
Incoming SMTP call from x.x.x.x at HH:mm:ss.
<<< 220 mail.foo.com
>>> QUIT
<<< 221 mail.foo.com closing
Incoming SMTP call from x.x.x.x completed at HH:mm:ss. ----
---- 4 SMTPRS log entry made at mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss
Incoming SMTP call from x.x.x.x at HH:mm:ss.
<<< 220 mail.foo.com
>>> QUIT
<<< 221 mail.foo.com closing
Incoming SMTP call from x.x.x.x completed at HH:mm:ss.
---- 5 SMTPRS log entry made at mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss
Incoming SMTP call from x.x.x.x at HH:mm:ss.
<<< 220 mail.foo.com
>>> QUIT
<<< 221 mail.foo.com closing
Incoming SMTP call from x.x.x.x completed at HH:mm:ss. 
---- 6 SMTPRS log entry made at mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss ----
Incoming SMTP call from x.x.x.x at HH:mm:ss.
<<< 220 mail.foo.com
>>> QUIT
<<< 221 mail.foo.com closing
Incoming SMTP call from x.x.x.x completed at HH:mm:ss.
'
clear

[regex]$Regex = '(?m)^----\s(.*?)\s(log\sentry)\s(.*?)\s(mm\/dd\/yyyy\sHH:mm:ss)(?sm).*?^(.*?)(?=^----|\Z)'
# [regex]$Regex = '(?sm)----((?!----).*?)(log\sentry)((?!----).*?)(mm\/dd\/yyyy\sHH:mm:ss)((?!----).*?)'

# cycle through all matches
$intCount = 0
Measure-Command {
    $Regex.matches($String) | foreach {
            $intCount += 1
            Write-Host "[$intCount][0]=" $_.Groups[0].Value
            Write-Host "[$intCount][1]=" $_.Groups[1].Value
            Write-Host "[$intCount][2]=" $_.Groups[2].Value
            Write-Host "[$intCount][3]=" $_.Groups[3].Value
            Write-Host "[$intCount][4]=" $_.Groups[4].Value
            Write-Host "[$intCount][5]=" $_.Groups[5].Value

        } # next match
    } | select Milliseconds
```

**Output**

```
[1][0]= ---- 1 SMTPRS log entry made at mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss
Incoming SMTP call from x.x.x.x at HH:mm:ss.
<<< 220 mail.foo.com
>>> QUIT
<<< 221 mail.foo.com closing
Incoming SMTP call from x.x.x.x completed at HH:mm:ss.

[1][1]= 1 SMTPRS
[1][2]= log entry
[1][3]= made at
[1][4]= mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss
[1][5]= Incoming SMTP call from x.x.x.x at HH:mm:ss.
<<< 220 mail.foo.com
>>> QUIT
<<< 221 mail.foo.com closing
Incoming SMTP call from x.x.x.x completed at HH:mm:ss.

[2][0]= ---- 2 SMTPRS log entry made at mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss ----
Incoming SMTP call from x.x.x.x at HH:mm:ss.
<<< 220 mail.foo.com
>>> QUIT
<<< 221 mail.foo.com closing
Incoming SMTP call from x.x.x.x completed at HH:mm:ss.

[2][1]= 2 SMTPRS
[2][2]= log entry
[2][3]= made at
[2][4]= mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss
[2][5]= Incoming SMTP call from x.x.x.x at HH:mm:ss.
<<< 220 mail.foo.com
>>> QUIT
<<< 221 mail.foo.com closing
Incoming SMTP call from x.x.x.x completed at HH:mm:ss.

[3][0]= ---- 3 SMTPRS log entry made at mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss
Incoming SMTP call from x.x.x.x at HH:mm:ss.
<<< 220 mail.foo.com
>>> QUIT
<<< 221 mail.foo.com closing
Incoming SMTP call from x.x.x.x completed at HH:mm:ss. ----

[3][1]= 3 SMTPRS
[3][2]= log entry
[3][3]= made at
[3][4]= mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss
[3][5]= Incoming SMTP call from x.x.x.x at HH:mm:ss.
<<< 220 mail.foo.com
>>> QUIT
<<< 221 mail.foo.com closing
Incoming SMTP call from x.x.x.x completed at HH:mm:ss. ----

[4][0]= ---- 4 SMTPRS log entry made at mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss
Incoming SMTP call from x.x.x.x at HH:mm:ss.
<<< 220 mail.foo.com
>>> QUIT
<<< 221 mail.foo.com closing
Incoming SMTP call from x.x.x.x completed at HH:mm:ss.

[4][1]= 4 SMTPRS
[4][2]= log entry
[4][3]= made at
[4][4]= mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss
[4][5]= Incoming SMTP call from x.x.x.x at HH:mm:ss.
<<< 220 mail.foo.com
>>> QUIT
<<< 221 mail.foo.com closing
Incoming SMTP call from x.x.x.x completed at HH:mm:ss.

[5][0]= ---- 5 SMTPRS log entry made at mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss
Incoming SMTP call from x.x.x.x at HH:mm:ss.
<<< 220 mail.foo.com
>>> QUIT
<<< 221 mail.foo.com closing
Incoming SMTP call from x.x.x.x completed at HH:mm:ss. 

[5][1]= 5 SMTPRS
[5][2]= log entry
[5][3]= made at
[5][4]= mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss
[5][5]= Incoming SMTP call from x.x.x.x at HH:mm:ss.
<<< 220 mail.foo.com
>>> QUIT
<<< 221 mail.foo.com closing
Incoming SMTP call from x.x.x.x completed at HH:mm:ss. 

[6][0]= ---- 6 SMTPRS log entry made at mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss ----
Incoming SMTP call from x.x.x.x at HH:mm:ss.
<<< 220 mail.foo.com
>>> QUIT
<<< 221 mail.foo.com closing
Incoming SMTP call from x.x.x.x completed at HH:mm:ss. [6][1]= 6 SMTPRS
[6][2]= log entry
[6][3]= made at
[6][4]= mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss
[6][5]= Incoming SMTP call from x.x.x.x at HH:mm:ss.
<<< 220 mail.foo.com
>>> QUIT
<<< 221 mail.foo.com closing
Incoming SMTP call from x.x.x.x completed at HH:mm:ss. 


Milliseconds
------------
16
```

Unfortunately on my system this expression runs slightly slower, but I'm not using real data. So I'm curious if you see any improvement with this

Comment: Thank you. I realize now how I was looking at it the wrong way. That regex ran so fast I can just parse all the log entries and process as the entries on the fly -- returning hits as as psobjects.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need regular expressions for parsing logs like that. Something like this should work as well:

```
$userInput = "..."

$logfile = 'C:\path\to\your.log'

$entry = $null
$log = Get-Content $logfile | % {
  $len = [Math]::Min(4, $_.Length)
  if ($_.SubString(0, $len) -eq '----' -and $entry -ne $null) {
    "$entry"
    $entry = $null
  }
  $entry += "$_`n"
}
$log += $entry

$log | ? { $_ -match [regex]::Escape($userInput) }
```